# Dynamic names for LinkedList Java

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I have a `LinkedList` of some type `<Structure>`. While looping through directories, i have some folders that i read it. I dynamically want to create the these `LinkedList` with the name of the read directory.

i.e. If directory read is `Kitchen` or `Lobby`. I want:

```
LinkedList<Structure> Kitchen = new LinkedList<Structure>();
LinkedList<Strucutre> Lobby = new LinkedList<Strucure>();
```

Structure object has `(String, ImageIcon, ImageIcon, ImageIcon)`

The question here is to name the LinkedList based on the names received by reading directories.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/to/directory/");
File file = new File(url.getPath() + "/");
File[] directories = file.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
     if (directories[i].isDirectory()) {
         // if directory then create LinkedList with that name
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to generate code based on these names?

Comment: I want to create new LinkedLists based on those retrieved names.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you want a new class, e.g.

```
class Room {
    private final String name;
    private final LinkedList<Structure> elements;

    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a `Map<String, LinkedList<Structure>>` and just populate the map as you load different files.

Then when you load each room, you can supply the name for the object. It's *very* important that you distinguish between variables (which have names) and objects (which don't, unless you add a field to represent that name, as I have above). Variable names are usually only relevant in code - so the idea of a "dynamically generated variable name" is pointless.

Comment: I am trying to use `Map<String, LinkedList<Structure>>`, but i am getting the error message saying Map is abstract, cannot be instantiated. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Namit.. You need to instantiate a concrete implementation of `Map`. for e.g: - a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this by use a `Map<String, LinkedList<Structure>>` where the String key to the Map is the directory name. Then you can access the related LinkedList easily via the directory String.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the Map<K, V>. I did have a look at the Documentation. Would you be able to explain this in a little more detail?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. The names of variables are just symbols you use for programming. At runtime all of this is reduced to references to some space in memory. Also there is no way you or anybody else would be able to actually see the names of those variables, so there's no point here anyway.

Comment: Exactly -- variable names have little meaning or use to the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Java variables names are not *variable* in themselves but you could go with [MultiMap<String, LinkedList<Structure>>](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). This would help deal with duplicate name entries.